# Scroll to custom Android View

Tags: android

I have implemented a custom View, a form field `MyFormField`, and I want to display an error indicator when the field has bad input. When the error indicator is shown, I should also **scroll to the field**, which is of course a child of a ScrollView.

I have tried `requestFocus()` but that has the undesired effect of requesting focus for one of the field's descendants, triggering some other behaviour related to that descendant. I would like to perform scrolling only.

Answer (score 2):

```
// field is an instance of MyFormField
Rect rect = new Rect(field.getLeft(), field.getTop(), field.getRight(), field.getBottom());
field.requestRectangleOnScreen(rect);
```

The purpose of the method `requestRectangleOnScreen` is precisely to "scroll to this view". From the [API Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestRectangleOnScreen%28android.graphics.Rect%29):

> Request that a rectangle of this view be visible on the screen, scrolling if necessary just enough.
>
> A View should call this if it maintains some notion of which part of its content is interesting. For example, a text editing view should call this when its cursor moves.

Depending on your `MyFormField`, you might want to `requestRectangleOnScreen` for a descendant, like this:

```
public class MyFormField extends View {
    private View descendant;

    // ...

    public boolean requestOnScreen() {
        Rect rect = new Rect(descendant.getLeft(), descendant.getTop(), descendant.getRight(), descendant.getBottom());
        return requestRectangleOnScreen(rect);
    }
}
```

And then simply call `field.requestOnScreen();`.